# What loves to talk but has little to say

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> What loves to talk but has little to say,
>   Nags you in the morning and throughout the day?

---

I get that this one comes across as too short or too broad. There's not much I can do about it now, but please understand I was trying for something inspired not only by Avigrail's wife but also short, simple riddles that play with the double meanings of words, like "Black and white and red all over".

I can imagine I would've got absolutely murdered if I went with my other idea instead: "What's fast unless it runs. And ruins the laundry."

Comment: I think we need a few more lines

Comment: must be about my wife

Comment: The first line makes me think of a brook, "babbling brook", but I don't see how that would be nagging me all day...

Comment: The funny thing is the second related question that comes up is "What was my wife trying to say?"

Comment: This is my feeling about most of AM radio

Comment: I see what you mean by "we need a few more lines" and how easily things can get marked "too broad" - lots of good answers already... I was aiming for something that felt more like one of those classic riddles that's short with a little word play, like "The beginning of the end and the end of time and space"... I'm curious to see how the community responds to short riddles tho, so I'm not going to touch this one for a bit.

Comment: Donald Trump and Hilary Clinton

Comment: And now I see how the community responds to short riddles... I WAS going to add more lines if it turned out it was too difficult or broad but, beastly, you actually had the right answer 2 minutes after I posted...

Comment: I think the riddle is fine as is. It often happens that a riddle looks too broad until you see the "trick". To me that's a good thing, but I'm outvoted :-)

Comment: You kind of deserved the answer, deep :/ Now I feel bad...

Comment: You got the trick, and you got my back, and you even didn't add punctuation to my riddle just for the sake of an edit...

Comment: Aww thanks :-) Well it's fair he was first and close. Anyway your comments are a virtual checkmark, they give me the internet validation I need. ;-)

Comment: 15 upvotes for commenting on the obvious inspiration behind the riddle. So many (ongoing) downvotes for the riddle itself :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> An alarm clock?
>  (or just a clock)

What loves to talk but has little to say

> I'm sure we all know the repetitive beeping sound
>
>  *"Talk" is a misspelling of the thing clocks do.*

Nags you in the morning and throughout the day

> Gets you up in the morning and is ringing in your head for the rest of the day
>
>  *Alarm clocks get you up in the morning. Old fashioned clocks may chime the hours throughout the day.*

Comment: For that last phrase, I think you need to get a better <insert noun here>...

Comment: Clock was the answer I was looking for. I love all the other creative answers, tho. But I see what you mean by 'too broad'. Anyway, giving it to you but I might make some edits.

Comment: @user1566694 ok, personally I thought 'yawn' was better :P

Comment: yeah, but like "a skunk on the highway" and "Alabama in the 50's" are better answers to "what's black and white and red all over", "newspaper" is still the right one

Answer (score 9):

This is a long shot but here goes...

> A yawn

What loves to talk but has little to say

> Opens your mouth but no words come out.

Nags you in the morning and throughout the day

> Yawning is common in the morning, but also during the day if you are tired.

Answer (score 9):

I could be:

> Your stomach

What loves to talk but has little to say

> A rumbling tummy is said to be your "tummy talking", but no words are spoken

Nags you in the morning and throughout the day

> You wake up hungry, and get hungry again during the day

Answer (score 6):

I want to say

> **Siri**

But she is not as nagging as

> **Google Assistant**

Because...

> Both voice assistants love to talk but don't have an independent say. They wake you up in the morning and nags you about meetings, reminders and wrong turns throughout the day (mine even nags about bed time :P)

Answer (score 6):

is it

> A phone?

What loves to talk but has little to say

> You 'talk' on your phone, and listen to it, but the phone itself does not say anything.

Nags you in the morning and throughout the day

> Many people use the alarms on their phone to wake them up, and it rings periodically throughout the day as well

Comment: You could add notifications for the second part

Answer (score 6):

Inspired by OP's comment about short riddles with a little wordplay, I'll guess it is a

> ticking clock.

It loves to talk but has little to say

> tick-TOCK... haha

Nags you in the morning and throughout the day

> rings out the hours

Comment: Great explanation. You hit it exactly. But I think Beastly technically had it first

Answer (score 3):

It could be

> a baby

What loves to talk but has little to say,

> babies make noises all day; they think they are talking but are rarely saying anything meaningful

Nags you in the morning and throughout the day?

> babies always seek attention (in a nagging way), especially in the morning when they are soiled and hungry

Comment: i feel like if it were a baby it'd nag you all night too, haha

Comment: yeah, babies are the worst

Answer (score 3):

Could it be:

> A cat?

What loves to talk but has little to say,

> Cats meow all the time, but they don't have many different sounds (though they do hiss)

Nags you in the morning and throughout the day?

> Cats meow whenever people are nearby, regardless of the time of day.

Comment: Well, some of them are more talkative than others. Some of them are quiet when people are around, but “talk” to others of their own kind. And they have ways of nagging you without making a sound.

Answer (score 1):

What loves to talk but has little to say

> Gabby Coworkers

Nags you in the morning and throughout the day?

> They can nag you first thing in the morning and also throughout the day

Answer (score 1):

> A consultant.

No further explanation required for those who have dealt with them.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Could you edit this answer to add in an explanation as to why you think it is correct? Thanks!